# Parse LinkedIn API response body to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, linkedin-api

This is driving me nuts and I'm hoping someone has encountered this & come up with a clean, elegant solution.  When making a JSON request to the LinkedIn REST Api, the body comes back as a string with new-line characters.  When I parse the string to JSON with JSON.parse it *appears* to create a JSON Object, but I can't access the values with dot notation using their relative keys.  I have tried escaping the new line characters, a combination of JSON.stringify then parsing, etc.  I cannot get this to work and it's obnoxious, though I'm sure there's a simple solution I'm overlooking.  Here's the response from the LinkedIn API:

> {"statusCode":200,"body":"{\n  \"numConnections\": 152,\n 
>   \"numConnectionsCapped\":
>   false\n}","headers":{"server":"Apache-Coyote/1.1","x-li-request-id":"myid","vary":"*","x-li-format":"json","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","date":"Tue,
>   10 Jan 2017 00:08:01
>   GMT","x-li-fabric":"prod-ltx1","transfer-encoding":"chunked","x-li-pop":"prod-ltx1","set-cookie":["lidc=\"b=TB70:g=489:u=129:i=1484006881:t=1484082637:s=AQG3LuLPqWuZiIoHGf2NqD8O7mRfdA4q\";
>   Expires=Tue, 10 Jan 2017 21:10:37 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com;
>   Path=/"],"x-li-uuid":"53NCd2VAmBSAAWKrrSoAAA=="},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"api.linkedin.com","port":443,"hostname":"api.linkedin.com","hash":null,"search":"?format=json","query":"format=json","pathname":"/v1/people/id=myid:(num-connections,num-connections-capped)","path":"/v1/people/id=myid:(num-connections,num-connections-capped)?format=json","href":"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=myid:(num-connections,num-connections-capped)?format=json"},"method":"GET","headers":{"authorization":"Bearer
>   mytoken"}}}

I'm trying to access the value with key "numConnections" but just can't get to the value.

Using `JSON.parse(response.body)` gets me this result:

> {"numConnections":152,"numConnectionsCapped":false}

however I still cannot access the values associated with each key using

`myObj.numConnections` or any of the other notation I've tried.  How can I get a valid JSON object out of this in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of parsing `response.body` is an object - on which you can use dot notation or bracket notation to access the values:

```
var parsedBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
parsedBody.numConnections //152
parsedBody['numConnections'] //152
```

Comment: To further on this, you should be able to validate using the Chrome console pretty easily - I was able to use `let y = JSON.parse(response.body)` without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was stupid.  I found that my issue was really with Express not allowing numeric values to be sent with res.send(num).  For some reason there was no error in the console as a resulting and I was receiving an undefined value with the get request.  Parsing the JSON was not the issue, but marked answer as valid.  If anyone else is having this issue, you need to stringify numeric values when separating them from the object if you want to send them as a response in Express!